# submit text to div using the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how I can add text to a div using the same id as the text area. What is happening right now, is that every time I try to enter a text it duplicates. All I want, is when I enter a text, I want it to be able to show according to the div id or class. The reason why it duplicates is because I only have 2 divs to display the text.

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

var vm = function() {
  var self=this;
  self.items=ko.observableArray();
  self.textContent1 = ko.observable('');
  self.textContent2 = ko.observable('');
  self.textContent3 = ko.observable('');
  self.init = function() {
    self.items([]);
  }
  self.remove = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.items.remove(item);
 }
 self.addNew = function() {
  var content = [ 
    self.textContent1(), 
    self.textContent2(), 
    self.textContent3()
  ].filter(function(item) {
    return item !== ''
  });
  content.forEach(function(item) { self.items.push(item); })
  self.textContent1('');
  self.textContent2('');
  self.textContent3('');
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<div class="item1">
  <textarea id="fid1" data-bind="value: textContent1" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <textarea id="fid2" data-bind="value: textContent2" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item3">
  <textarea id="fid3" data-bind="value: textContent3" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>

<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#" id="fid1" class="item1" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
      <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <center>
        <span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/>
      </center>
    </div><div href="#" id="fid2"class="item2" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
      <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <center>
        <span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Comment: `id` always have to be unique.. so you need to find some other option..

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Use `html5` `data-*` attribute and use the same value wherever you have duplicate `id`

Comment: IDs should (not necessarily 'must') be unique within the entire document.
You can check the article here. 
(Html5 - section 3.2.5.1)
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Do I need to put data attribute to my div also? Or just my text area?

Comment: im sorry for wasting your time i do not know how to fix my code